# boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, boost, cgal

I downloaded a project named [MVCClone](https://github.com/pablospe/MVCDemo/tree/master/src) from github. It's a **QT** project that needs CGAL to run. I installed **boost** and CGAL on my **Windows 10**. QT 5.5.1 mingw is installed.

When I build the project I get the error:

> boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory

in one of CGAL header files.

Here is the .pro file for QT project:

```
QT += core gui opengl

TARGET = MVCDemo
TEMPLATE = app

SRC_DIR = $${PWD}/src

SOURCES += $${SRC_DIR}/glwidget.cpp \
           $${SRC_DIR}/main.cpp \
           $${SRC_DIR}/mainwindow.cpp \
           $${SRC_DIR}/MVCCloner.cpp \
           $${SRC_DIR}/sourcewidget.cpp \
           $${SRC_DIR}/utils.cpp

HEADERS  += $${SRC_DIR}/CloningParameters.h \
            $${SRC_DIR}/CoordinatesMesh.h \
            $${SRC_DIR}/glwidget.h \
            $${SRC_DIR}/mainwindow.h \
            $${SRC_DIR}/mvcshaders.h \
            $${SRC_DIR}/MVCCloner.h  \
            $${SRC_DIR}/sourcewidget.h \
            $${SRC_DIR}/utils.h

## using pkg-config
#linux {
#    CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
#    PKGCONFIG += glu
#}

# CGAL
*-g++* {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -frounding-math
}
LIBS += -lCGAL -lgmp

RESOURCES += images/images.qrc \
             src/shaders.qrc

LIBS += "C:/dev/CGAL-4.8.1/lib/release/CGAL_Core-vc140-mt-4.8.1.lib"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/dev/CGAL-4.8.1/include"

LIBS+="C:\local\boost_1_61_0\lib64-msvc-14.0"
INCLUDEPATH +="C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.0"
```

Also I can't #include any boost headers in the project.

Comment: try replacing INCLUDEPATH +="C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.0" by INCLUDEPATH +="C:\local\boost_1_61_0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INCLUDEPATH +="C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.0"
```

should be:

```
INCLUDEPATH +="C:/local/boost_1_61_0/"
```

there you will find a folder named boost containing all headers.